# Javascript Regular expression to match text between a colon sign and sentences ended by a dot

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-greedy

Suppose I have a text like this:

> This is the title: \ titles always have a colon
> This is a regular sentence.
> A sentence always ends with a period.
> A sentence can
> span multiple lines.
> A sentence can contain numbers like 123.
> The phrase can also contain "text enclosed in double quotes"
> or 'text enclosed in single quotes'.
> Other symbols that may appear in sentences are
> the comma ,
> the semicolon ;
> the dollar sign $
> parentheses ( )
> the plus sign +
> the minus sign -
> and the square brackets[ ].
>
> This is an isolated phrase that the regular expression should not match.

How could I create a regex in javascript to match the text between the first colon* and the last full stop after `brackets[ ]`? (assuming there will be no other colon, if there are any, they will be enclosed in double quotes)

I've tried using `:.*` but it maches all lines.

Comment: Isn't that `:[^.]*`?

Comment: It only matches the first line below the colon. I've tried `.\n{2}` to detect more than on linefeed.

Comment: No, it matches [from `:` till `.`](https://regex101.com/r/3jvFhi/1). That is already 2 lines. What do you expect to match here and why?

Comment: It matches from `:` till the first period right after the word `sentence`. I want the last period. after the word `brackets[ ].`

Comment: The regex `:.+?(\n\n)` seems to work fine, but just if the text has two linefeeds

Comment: @ElenderGóisGallas To me this reads like "After a line with an unenclosed colon, get every successive line that does not contain just a new line" so I would make the expression reflect that. Besides readability, this should also improve performance. Something like: `:([^"\n]*$(?:\r?\n[ \t]*\S.*)+)`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Eg5gsQ/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [s](https://javascript.info/regexp-introduction) flag, the following regex captures everything after the colon till the double linebreak.

```
/(?<=:).*?(?=(?:\r?\n)+[^\n]*$)/sg
```

Test on regex101 [here](https://regex101.com/r/j7qOSq/4)

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. The text provided in the question was just a sample of the characters that could appear. they will not always appear (like the square brackets, for example. In your example, if the text does not have square brackets at the end, it is not captured.

Comment: I changed the regex to `/(?<=:).*?\n\.*?$/smg` since I wanted to match all valid ocurrences.

Comment: Thx. But I've adapted the regex anyway.